# Dynamically generated button's Click event is not firing every time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a method that gets called which creates a table with a button in it. The method - minus unecessary code - like this:

```
public void CreateButtonTable(_Default def, Table tblConfirmation)
{
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();

    Button btnConfirm = new Button();
    btnConfirm.Text = "Confirm";

    btnConfirm.Click += new EventHandler(def.btnConfirm_Click);

    cell.Controls.Add(btnConfirm);

    row.Cells.Add(cell);

    tblConfirmation.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

I call this method in two scenarios.

The first is in the `Page_Load()` method if the request has a specific QueryString variable.

The second is further down in the normal flow of the application.

***Clicking the button only fires the btnConfirm_Click method when the CreateButtonTable method is called from the `Page_Load()` method (i.e. the first scenario).***

I've debugged it and in both cases; the table is being created, the button is being created, the click event method is being set, and it looks the exact same. But during the normal flow of the application, the btnConfirm_Click method does not fire.

One thing I noticed while debugging is that in the first scenario, when I click on the generated button, the debugger flips back to the line above where the Click event is being set (`btnConfirm.Click += new EventHandler(def.btnConfirm_Click);`), then it goes back to the main page and into the btnConfirm_Click method.

But in the second scenario, it doesn't flip back to the CreateButtonTable method. Instead the table disappears (or is cleared).

I have no idea what the issue is and been stuck for a while.

Comment: Where is your event handler "def.btnConfirm_Click"?

Comment: @habib In the code-behind of the Default.aspx page

Comment: The problem occurs because its a dynamical control. For this to work you have to recreate the button everytime. It works first time because its created. Second time the server has no idea so you have to call createbuttontable if you wanna make it work.

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan But the button is there and I can click it. Why would I have to recreate the button just for the event (that should have already been fired when I clicked it) to fire? If I recreate it again, then I have to click it once the first time, and then after the `Page_Load` and after it has been recreated, click it again? Doesn't that then just cause the same issue over and over again?

Comment: The button exists on the client but not on the server. Unless you recreate it, it will not fire the event because there is no button on the serverside.